# How do I enable print selection in Chromium

Tags: printing, chromium, pdf, virtual-printer

For my own archive I want to print posts from an internet magazine to pdf files. I use Chromium 12.0.742.112 (90304) on Ubuntu 11.04, but the default option to save to pdf doesn't support selection (of parts to print). I know I can [install](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-create-pdf-documents-in-ubuntu.html) cups-pdf, but I prefer to not have a duplicate pdf solution.
Is there any way to make this option of print selection in Chromium available myself, until Google implements this option? (It is already present in Chrome with the same version nr. on Windows XP)

Kind regards

Comment: There is also a website/extension/bookmarklet available on http://www.printwhatyoulike.com which lets you select the bare content of a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until selection-printing will be enabled in Chromium you may be happy with the Chrome/Chromium [Print Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search?q=print+plus) extension that (partly) enables selecting elements from a page to print.

[image]

Unfortunately selecting from PDF documents is not so easy and may be limited to whole pages.

Comment: +1 for the extension.  Hope you don't mind I added a link to the Chromium bug report. (Edit, and now I rolled back because apparently the bug I linked to has been fixed.)

Comment: Although I was thinking of sth that enabled 'selection' in the printer window, the extension mentioned works perfect! Thanks.